# How handle ionic infinite reload the ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I built IPA for ios platform and tried to run on real iPhone device but the happens :

1- show splash screen

2- show the default(login) page

3- show a white page

4- infinite restart the app on the device !!

> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2 ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0 global packages:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)  local packages:
>
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4 Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.5 Ionic
>   Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9 System:
>
> ios-deploy : 1.9.4  Node       : v12.6.0 npm        : 6.9.0  OS
>   : macOS Xcode      : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001

the Xcode version is: 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by removing big load picture in app.html